# Regex: remove all except first character and last number

Tags: regex, r

I know that `^.` is first character and `(\d+)(?!.*\d)` is last number. I've tried using `|` between these and have been trying to find code for the second character, but with no success.

This is in `R`.

Take for example:

`'ABCD some random words and spaces 1234'` should output `'A4'` when I do

`sub([regex here], "", 'ABCD some random words and spaces 1234')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you used `^.|(\d+)(?!.*\d)`, the pattern would only match the first char and remove it with `sub`, and would remove the first char and the last 1+ digits if used with `gsub` without backreferences in the replacement pattern. See [this pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/gD1cB3/1).

You can use

```
sub("^(.).*(\\d).*$", "\\1\\2", "ABCD some random words and spaces 1234")
```

See the [R demo](http://ideone.com/xC79aY) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mH0yU8/1).

This TRE regex pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.)`  - Group 1 capturing any char
- `.*` - 0+ any chars as many as possible up to the last...
- `(\\d)` - Group 2 capturing a digit
- `.*` - the rest of the string
- `$` - end of string.

The `\\1\\2` replacement pattern re-inserts the values captured with Group 1 and Group 2 back to the result.

Comment: Thank you. As a side question, how do people go about learning Regex? There seem to be a plethora of resources online, but it's so much to take in.

Comment: There is a problem, yeah. In Base R, you have a choice between TRE regex (in `grep`, `sub`, etc.) if you do not use the `perl=TRUE` argument. If you use it, you will have to use PCRE regex flavor. With stringr/stringi, etc., you will need to read about ICU regex. There are plenty of resources on the Web, but there are "official" pages. [*PCRE - Perl Compatible Regular Expressions*](http://www.pcre.org), [*ICU*](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp), [*TRE*](http://laurikari.net/tre/documentation/regex-syntax/).